# ¿Cómo evitar la codificación de caracteres cuando codifico a JSON un array? PHP

Tags: php, json

Tengo un array simple en PHP.

```
$brasil = array("Brasília - Brasilia, Federal District, Brazil");
```

Y cuando paso a JSON:

```
echo json_encode( $brasil );
```

Me muestra:

```
Brasu00edlia - Brasilia, Federal District, Brazil
```

Pues parece que la "í" de `Brasília` la transforma a `u00ed` y quisiera que quedara con la "í" normal.

Gracias.

Comment: Si usas PHP 5.4.0 o superior puedes pasar como parámetro de opción `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. Sería algo como `json_encode( $brasil, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );`. Prueba eso y nos comentas.

Comment: Si men, me sirvió muchas gracias!